# treeSet serialization in java

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class that extend a super class which implement serializable itself. My class contains a `treeSet` field and a connected comparator. I would like to make the class serializable because I'm going to run it on the cluster. 
I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException` error while accessing `treeSet` field. 
Does any one know how I should resolve it?

```
public static class bounderyRecordsFilter implements FilterFunction  {
    public ArrayList<String> sortingkeyStart;
    public ArrayList<String> sortingkeyEnd;
    public  TreeSet<boundery> intervals ;
    public int pass;

       public   Comparator<boundery> Interval_order =   new Comparator<boundery>() {
            public int compare(boundery e1, boundery e2) {
                int comp_res=0;
                     comp_res= e1.getStartInterval() .compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getStartInterval());
                return comp_res;
            }
        };  

    public bounderyRecordsFilter(ArrayList<String> sortingkeyStart,ArrayList<String> sortingkeyEnd, int pass){
        super();
        intervals = new TreeSet<boundery>(Interval_order);
        for (int i=0 ; i< 4 ; i++)
        {
            boundery tempInterval = new boundery();
            ...             
            intervals.add(tempInterval) ;
        }
         this.sorkingkeyStart = sorkingkeyStart ; 
         this.sorkingkeyEnd = sorkingkeyEnd ;
         this.pass = pass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Tuple2<Integer, String> inputTuple)
            throws Exception {
        boundery tempInterval = new boundery();
        boundery outputInterval = new boundery();

        tempInterval .setStartInterval(inputTuple.f19);
        outputInterval  = intervals.lower(tempInterval);

        if (outputInterval. getEndInterval().compareToIgnoreCase(inputTuple.f2) >0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;


    }
```

}

Comment: If you post your code, it will be helpful I guess

Comment: What type of data you have in `TreeSet`?. The class of fields inside `TreeSet` need to implement `Serializable` interface

Comment: I just added the code. In treeSet I have just String and Integer.

Comment: What is `boundery`, is `boundery` and all its members and super classes serializable?

Comment: boundery is serializable. If instead of treeSet  I use an ArrayList and delete the comparator, every things will be fine and code works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to make both `boundery` and the `Comparator` you are using `Serializable`.  You haven't provided much in the way of details about `boundery`, but a popular way to make the `Comparator` serializable would be to write it like so:

```
enum IntervalOrder implements Comparator<boundery> {
   INSTANCE;
   public int compare(boundery e1, boundery e2) {
     return e1.getStartInterval() .compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getStartInterval());
   }
};
```

and then to write `new TreeSet<boundery>(IntervalOrder.INSTANCE)`.  Enums are automatically serializable and singletons.

Answer (score 1):

The Comparator class has to implement `Serializable` too.
Like this:

```
public class StringComperator implements Comparator<String>, Serializable
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String n1, String n2)
    {
        return n1.compareTo(n2);
    }
}
```